# `auto` for the result of `std::set::find` in non-const context resolves to `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator` in g++ (GCC) 7.3.0 with `-std=c++11`

Tags: c++, c++11

Disclaimer: I am not very accustomed with working with C++11, especially with new semantics like `auto` and `move`.

I am trying to keep a `O(log(n))` random access memory structure of simple `struct`s sorted with respect to their first elements, with `O(1)` access to min/max elements. C++11 STL's `set` class provides exactly this, so tried implementing my design with it using g++ (GCC) 7.3.0 and preparing an overload for `operator<`. Since typing templated types every time is pain, I used `auto` for the result of the `std::set::find` member function as follows:

Minimal sample:

```
#include <set>

template <typename X> struct _get_auto_type;

struct A {
  int x;
  char y;
  bool operator<(const A &a) const { return x < a.x; }
};

int main(void)
{
  typedef std::set<A> A_set;
  A_set a_set{{1, 'a'}, {0, 'b'}, {2, 'c'}};
  auto a_it = a_set.find({0, 'b'});
  a_it->y++;
  _get_auto_type<decltype(a_it)> _gat;
  return 0;
}
```

g++ output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 possible_gcc_bug.cpp
possible_gcc_bug.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
possible_gcc_bug.cpp:16:34: error: aggregate ‘_get_auto_type<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<A> > _gat’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   _get_auto_type<decltype(a_it)> _gat;
                                  ^~~~
possible_gcc_bug.cpp:17:10: error: increment of member ‘A::y’ in read-only object
   a_it->y++;
          ^~
```

The two cases where this result is expected are:

1. Compiler has a bug (my initial guess), or
2. `std::set`'s `Key` values are rvalues only, which seems more reasonable but I couldn't find any solid evindence for this.

Are either of my guesses correct, and if the 2nd one is true, which data structure (preferably from STL) can I use instead?

Comment: The correct way to alter the contents of a set is to extract the value, modify it, and reinsert it.  The set maintains the items in a particular structure based on their value; if you change them without removing/inserting them, you can end up with the layout of the elements being wrong.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont In reality what I had clumsily implemented here was `std::map`: Those members that I modify didn't affect the total ordering of the set, so dividing them into keys and values solved my problem. Otherwise, yes, your point about `std::set` is correct. Thanks for the input anyways.

Comment: you could also mark members as mutable ;)  (usually a bad idea)